# How to downgrade chrome to version 87.0.4280.88 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I tried to find the package for above said version for chrome from [this link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable?id=202706&page=6) but i'm unable to find it. Where can i find the said package and what would be the steps to downgrade chrome on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all uninstall your current version of Chrome

```
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
$ mv ~/.config/google-chrome/ ~/.config/google-chrome.bak/
```

Then install the preferred version choosing from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable) and replacing the `${CHROME_VERSION}` on the code below with the version you need (in this case 87.0.4280.88-1 )

```
wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb \
  && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb \
  && rm /tmp/chrome.deb
```